# Unable to change values when change spinner item

Tags: java, android, spinner

What i am doing is making a unit converter app although its running good but when i change the spinner item from ***INCHES to FOOT*** the values didn't change but when i add or delete a number from `EditText` box its get updated to foot parameter values.

What i want is when i enter the values in textbox it gets updated the values according the item selected in `Spinner` , For example: if i write 23 and the `Spinner` item is ***INCHES*** then it shows me all values according to inches conversion and when i click `Spinner` and change it to ***FEET*** it will show me values according to feet conversion But this is not happening in my case this is only happened when i add/delete some number in textbox it gets updated to FEET.

Here is Length.java file

```
package com.example.farrukh.convertmee;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Length extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener

{
    String[] Lunits = {"Inches", "Feet", "Yards", "Miles", "Km", "Meters" ,"Centimeters" };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.length_layout,null);


        final View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.length_layout, container, false); //get laength.xml
        final Spinner spin = (Spinner)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        final  TextView a=(TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        final  TextView b=(TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        final  TextView c=(TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        final  TextView d=(TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        final  TextView e=(TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView13);
        final  TextView f=(TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView14);
        final  TextView g=(TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView15);

        final  EditText text =(EditText)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.editText);

        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

                text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
                    {

                        double ans=0;
                        if( !s.toString().equals("") && s.toString().length() > 0 )
                        {

                            ans = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                        }

                        if(spin.getSelectedItem().equals("Inches"))
                        {
                            double inches = ( ans * 1 );
                            a.setText(" "+inches);

                            double feet = ( ans * 0.0833 );
                            b.setText(" "+feet);

                            double yards = ( ans * 0.02777778 );
                            c.setText(" " + yards);

                            double miles = ( ans * (1/63360) );
                            d.setText(" " + miles);

                            double kilometers = ( (ans/39370) );
                            e.setText(" " + kilometers);

                            double meters = ( ans * 0.0254 );
                            f.setText(" " + meters);

                            double centimeters = ( ans * 2.54 );
                            g.setText(" "+centimeters);
                        }

                        if (spin.getSelectedItem().equals("Feet"))
                        {
                            double inches = ( ans * 12 );
                            a.setText(" "+inches);

                            double feet = ( ans * 1 );
                            b.setText(" "+feet);

                            double yards = ( ans * 0.3333333 );
                            c.setText(" " + yards);

                            double miles = ( ans * (0.0001893939) );
                            d.setText(" " + miles);

                            double kilometers = ( ans * 0.0003048 );
                            e.setText(" " + kilometers);

                            double meters = ( ans * 0.3048 );
                            f.setText(" " + meters);

                            double centimeters = ( ans * 30.48 );
                            g.setText(" "+centimeters);
                        }

                    }


                });


            }


            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });




        ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Lunits);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(aa);


        return myFragmentView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Comment: visit here it will help you.  https://sites.google.com/site/myajdeguzman/home/android/simple-android-unit-converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `EditText` ans `TextView`s as class variable (there is no need for *final*), and add the `TextWatcher` outside the `Sipnner` listener.

Here is my suggestion:

```
 public class Length extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener

    {
        String[] Lunits = {"Inches", "Feet", "Yards", "Miles", "Km", "Meters" ,"Centimeters" };

        EditText mEditText;
        TextView a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
        String mSelectedUnit = "";

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.length_layout,null);


            final View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.length_layout, container, false); //get laength.xml
            Spinner spin = (Spinner)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            a=(TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView9);
            b=(TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
            c=(TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
            d=(TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
            e=(TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView13);
            f=(TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView14);
            g=(TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView15);

            mEditText =(EditText)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.editText);


            ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Lunits);
            aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spin.setAdapter(aa);
            spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                     mSelectedUnit = Lunits[position];
                     convertValue();

                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });


           mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

              @Override
              public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
              }

              @Override
              public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
              }

              @Override
              public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
              {
                 convertValue();
              }

          });

            return myFragmentView;
        }

        private void convertValue(){
           double ans=0;
           String s = mEditText.getText().toString(); 

           if( !s.toString().equals("") && s.length() > 0 )
           {
              ans = Double.parseDouble(s);
           }

           if(mSelectedUnit.equals("Inches"))
           {
              double inches = ( ans * 1 );
              a.setText(" "+inches);

              double feet = ( ans * 0.0833 );
              b.setText(" "+feet);

              double yards = ( ans * 0.02777778 );
              c.setText(" " + yards);

              double miles = ( ans * (1/63360) );
              d.setText(" " + miles);

              double kilometers = ( (ans/39370) );
              e.setText(" " + kilometers);

              double meters = ( ans * 0.0254 );
              f.setText(" " + meters);

              double centimeters = ( ans * 2.54 );
              g.setText(" "+centimeters);
           }

           if (mSelectedUnit.equals("Feet"))
           {
               double inches = ( ans * 12 );
               a.setText(" "+inches);

               double feet = ( ans * 1 );
               b.setText(" "+feet);

               double yards = ( ans * 0.3333333 );
               c.setText(" " + yards);

               double miles = ( ans * (0.0001893939) );
               d.setText(" " + miles);

               double kilometers = ( ans * 0.0003048 );
               e.setText(" " + kilometers);

               double meters = ( ans * 0.3048 );
               f.setText(" " + meters);

               double centimeters = ( ans * 30.48 );
               g.setText(" "+centimeters);
           }

         }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou it helped me and figure out my mistakes  ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {` listener. Whenever you are selecting the different item from spinner, `onItemSelected` is called but then you have a `TextWatcher` inside it which will be called only when the text in `EditText` changes.

If you want the conversion at both (spinner item selection and text change) then move whole conversion code in a separate method and call it from both the listeners (`OnItemSelectedListener` and `TextWatcher`) **But** `TextWatcher` need to be independent not inside the other listener.